# Count number of majority value cross rows in Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like:

```
df = np.array([[1,5,3,4,5,5,6,],[1,2,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,6]])         
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

and my expected output is the majority value of each row, like:

```
0 5                      
1 2
2 6
```

I'm new with Pandas. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with pandas version 0.13.0, you can use `df.mode(axis = 1)`

(check your version with `pd.__version__`)

```
df.mode(axis=1)

   0
0  5
1  2
2  6

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! And how could I change the output to a list, like [5, 2, 6], I used to use np.array do this in 0.12.0, but it seems doesn't now.

Comment: if you want to use np.array then `mymode = df.mode(axis = 1)` and use `np.array(mymode)` or maybe directly on the dataframe, like `list(mymode[0])`

Comment: Thank you so much! I got exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are looking for is a mode, which is the most commonly occurring number in a set. Scipy and Pandas both have ways to handle modes, through scipy.stats.mode and pandas.DataFrame.mode(works along an axis). So for this example you could say:

```
df = np.array([[1,5,3,4,5,5,6,],[1,2,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,6]])
for i in np.arange(len(df)):
    results = np.zeros(len(df))
    results[i] = scipy.stats.mode(df[i])
```

This should return a numpy array with the modes of each array. To do this same thing with Pandas you can do:

```
df = np.array([[1,5,3,4,5,5,6,],[1,2,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,6]])
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.mode(axis = 1)
```

The documentation is here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html